# Change index in json construction

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code in order to construct a json object :

```
var myJSONObject = [];
var id = "1", value = "I'm a value !";
myJSONObject.push({id:value});
```

After this construction, when I display I get something like : `[{"id":"I'm a value !"}]`

But I'd like to have the following thing : `[{"1":"I'm a value !"}]`
How could I do ?

Comment: `myJSONObject[0]['1'] = myJSONObject[0]['id']; myJSONObject[0]['id'] = undefined;` I guess. There are no "JSON objects".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need bracket notation:

```
var myJSONObject = [];
var id = "1", value = "I'm a value !";
var obj = {};
obj[id] = value;
// ^------- THIS!
myJSONObject.push(obj);
```

And since your key is numeric, you'll need bracket notation to read it too:

```
console.log(myJSONObject[0][1]); // or "1"; both will log "I'm a value"
```

---

Also, note that what you're calling a "JSON object" (there's no such thing!) is actually a JavaScript array, containing one JavaScript object inside. If you want JSON (e.g. to POST it to a server), you can use:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myJSONObject);
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem :) And I knew for the stringify method in order to post it to a server ;)